# How can I find out my system's DHCPv6 DUID?

Tags: dhcp

I would like to assign a static IPv6 address to my machine running Ubuntu Server 15 using DHCPv6. To do so, I need to know the [DUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6#DHCP_Unique_Identifier) used by the DHCP client so I can assign the static IP to it in my network's DHCP server.

How can I find out which DUID is being used?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu server calls dhclient with a few flags, but mostly default options, and it therefore defaults to a type 1 DUID-LLT DUID.  Ubuntu desktop uses Network Manager which then calls dhclient with a type 4 DUID-UUID DUID.

For servers, it puts it in /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.......lease
For desktop, it puts it in /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6.......lease

It's a weird string that looks like:
default-duid "\000\001\000\001\037\305\371\341\001\002\003\004\005\006"

Here's a short script you can use to convert it to a normal hex format duid.
Just run the script like:

```
./script '\000\001\000\001\037\305\371\341\001\002\003\004\005\006'
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf $1 | hexdump -e '14/1 "%02x " "\n"' | sed 's/ /:/g'
```

Comment: my dhclient6..lease file has the following: "\000\004\354\352~\365\017\375\330\201!\230+<Oj\031\302" which returns an error with your script. Any ideas?

Comment: Replace the double quotes with single quotes because there are characters like ! in your duid lease file and change the `14/1` to `18/1` in the script to account for the longer length of type 4 duid's.  I think the script originally came from some redhat documentation and only had type 1 and type 3 duid's in mind.

Comment: actually, I found even better was to add `-s 2` to skip some of the pre-amble, e.g.:

`hexdump -s 2 -e '14/1 "%02x " "\n"'  /var/lib/dhcpv6/dhcp6c_duid`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DHCP with ISC dhcpd look in:

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf`

---

If you are using dibbler as dhcp client check for the DUID in:

`/var/lib/dibbler/client-duid`

It might also be worth checking in `/etc/dibbler/client.conf` if any other bits are there.